# Are expected order statistics always concave in sample size?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expectation, order-statistics

Let $X_{1:n}\leqslant X_{2:n}\leqslant \dots \leqslant X_{n:n}$ be the $n$ (independent) order statistics of a known distribution with CDF $F(x)$. Consider the expectation of the $k$-th ***largest*** order statistics, i.e., $\mathbb{E}(X_{n-k+1:n})$, is it always concave in $n$? Formally, is the following relationship always true? $$\mathbb{E}(X_{(n+1)-k+1:(n+1)})-\mathbb{E}(X_{n-k+1:n})>\mathbb{E}(X_{(n+2)-k+1:(n+2)})-\mathbb{E}(X_{(n+1)-k+1:(n+1)})$$
where $n$ is finite. Thanks!

Comment: So let's think qualitatively about *why* this is concave in $n$ for the uniform distribution. It's not hard to see: $X_{n-k+1:n}$ is converging in probability to the maximum, which is finite, so it can only increase so fast. If instead we take a distribution which is not bounded above, it *still* can probably only increase so fast, since the convergence in probability to $+\infty$ must slow down, otherwise presumably you couldn't have a normalized distribution.

Comment: I agree with you that the conclusion is quite intuitive for distributions bounded from the above. For unbounded distributions, this claim is also true for exponential distribution and Weibull. Makes me wonder if anything can be said for the general case.

Comment: I think it must be true for the general case at least for sufficiently large $n$, because the driving force is the convergence in probability to $+\infty$ which must necessarily slow down, because the tail of any distribution must decay.

Answer (score 1):

After some literature search, I realized that this claim is true for the **largest** expected order statistics. The following illustration uses results from [David (1997)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167715297000667). To be consistent, I use their notation. Denote $\mu_{r:n}$ as the $r$-th smallest expected order statistics out of $n$ order statistics (or equivalently, the $(n-r+1)$-th largest one), where $r\in\{1,2,...,n-1\}$, David (1997) shows that $$\mu_{r+1:n}-\mu_{r:n-1}=\binom{n-1}{r}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F^r(x)[1-F(x)]^{n-r}dx$$

Let $r=n-1$, i.e., consider the **largest** expected order statistics, then the above relationship becomes $$\mu_{n:n}-\mu_{n-1:n-1}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F^{n-1}(x)[1-F(x)]dx$$

Similarly, increase both $r$ and $n$ by 1, we get $$\mu_{n+1:n+1}-\mu_{n:n}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F^n(x)[1-F(x)]dx$$

Because $F(x)$, as the CDF of a distribution, is always between 0 and 1, we get $$\mu_{n+1:n+1}-\mu_{n:n}<\mu_{n:n}-\mu_{n-1:n-1}$$ indicating concavity.

However, this argument does not seem to easily generalize to other expected order statistics, because of the binomial coefficients. Or maybe I'm missing something obvious. Hope this can help people obtain a more generalized result.

(Update 09/22/2017) This claim is **not** always true for expected order statistics that are not the largest. Here is an (numeric) counter-example:

Consider a Weibull distribution of shape parameter 0.4 and scale parameter 1. The **second largest** expected order statistics out of samples of 3, 4, and 5 (i.e., $n=3,4,5$) are 1.336, 2.131, and 2.931 respectively, which is convex with respect to $n$. Even more evidently, the **third largest** expected order statistics are 0.213, 0.541, 0.931 respectively, also convex in $n$. These numbers were calculated based on results in [Lieblein (1955)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2236889?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

In summary, the **largest** expected order statistics always increase *concavely* with respect to sample size, irrespective of distribution. However, the same cannot be said for other expected order statistics.

Comment: Can you include the general formula for $\mu_{r_1:n_1}-\mu_{r_2:n_2}$ in the question?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a general formula for $\mu_{r_1:n_1}-\mu_{r_2:n_2}$ where $r_1,r_2,n_1,n_2$ are all arbitrary. The formula for $\mu_{r+1:n}-\mu_{r:n-1}$ is in the above answer - please feel free to edit the question as you see fit.

Comment: Well, in the absolutely continuous case there is definitely a formula for $\mu_{r:n}$ as an integral. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution

Comment: The issue is that now the integrand includes a binomial coefficient that tends to create the reverse of the concavity that you expected. However, the exponential term in $n$. However, the exponential term is presumably dominant for large $n$ at fixed $n-k$, so presumably you have the desired concavity at least for sufficiently large $n$.